# MYSQL joining 3 tables with left join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have these tables:

```
pupils: (id_pupil, name, surname, email, user, pass, level, class)
incidents: (id_incidents, date, time, type_incident, comments, id_pupil, id_user, subject, id_trimester)
qualifications: (id_qualification, qualification, date, time, subject, id_pupil, id_user, id_trimester, type_qualification)
```

and i did this query:

```
SELECT 
    pupils.id_pupil
  , name
  , surname
  , round(avg(qualifications.calificacion),2) as average
  , count(qualifications.calificacion) as count
  , COALESCE(sum(type_incident='miss' and level=1 and class='A' and id_trimester=1),0) as misses
  , COALESCE(sum(type_incident='delay' and level=1 and class='A' and id_trimester=1),0) as delays
  , COALESCE(sum(type_incident='attitude' and level=1 and class='A' and id_trimester=1),0) as attitude
  , COALESCE(sum(type_incident='miss_justif' and level=1 and class='A' and id_trimester=1),0) as misses_justificadas 
FROM 
    pupils 
    left join incidents         ON incidents.id_pupil=pupils.id_pupil
    left join qualifications    ON qualifications.id_pupil=pupils.id_pupil
WHERE 
    level=1
    and class='A' 
    and id_trimester=1 
    and type_qualification='class' 
    and qualifications.id_trimester=incidents.id_trimester
GROUP BY id_pupil
```

But the problem is, the correct result i would have to get it would be:

[image]

And i get:

[image]

The problem is that multiplicate the number of class qualifications and the misses (17x6(2 misses, 1 delay, 1 attitude and 2 misses_just)=102)) and i don´t want that. I want the correct information showed in the first picture.

Would you like to help me, please?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to do the aggregation in subqueries, and then join with that.

Comment: And how i can do it? I don´t know, sorry

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate of that question, but my answer shows how to do the join with a subquery.

Comment: It's good practice to qualify all columns - exactly as you did with `qualifications.id_trimester` and `incidents.id_trimester`. It makes your code much more readable for others (and using thoughtful aliases helps even more).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the relations you are creating are duplicating lots of rows.

My personal approach would be:

1. First get the data you need from a `incidents`
2. Join that "subquery" to the data you need from pupils and qualifications

Something like this:

```
select 
    p.id_pupil, p.name, p.surname, 
    (case
        when type_incident = 'miss' and level = 1 and class='A' then incident_count 
        else 0
    end) as misses,
    (case
        when type_incident = 'delay' and level = 1 and class='A' then incident_count 
        else 0
    end) as delays,
    (case
        when type_incident = 'attitude' and level = 1 and class='A' then incident_count 
        else 0
    end) as attitude,
    (case
        when type_incident = 'miss_justif' and level = 1 and class='A' then incident_count 
        else 0
    end) as miss_justif
from 
    pupils as p
    left join (
        select id_pupil, class, id_trimester, type_qualification, avg(qualification) as q_avg
        from qualifications
        group by id_pupil, class, id_trimester, type_qualification
    ) as q on p.id_pupil = q.id_pupil
    left join (
        select id_pupil, class, type_incident, level, class, count(id_incidents) as incident_count
        from incidents
        group by id_pupil, id_trimester, incident, level, class
    ) as i on p.id_pupil = i.id_pupil
where ...
```

Comment: It says me doesn´t know about class column...